# A calculation involving the normalized area measure

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, integration

I am reading about the Dirichlet Space right now. The definition of a Dirichlet space is the set of all holomorphic functions in the unit disc that are finite with respect to the semi-norm:
$\mid \mid f \mid \mid$ = $\int _D \mid f^' (z)\mid ^2 dA(z)$

Here $dA$ is the normalized area measure, because we define $dA(x+iy)= \frac 1 \pi dx dy$. In the complex case, homorphicity and analyticity are equivalent, so we can say $f(z)=\sum^\infty_0a_nz^n$, then **because** $dA$ is an area normalizing measure, we can say $\mid \mid f \mid \mid$ = $\int _D \mid f^' (z)\mid ^2 dA(z)$ = $\int _D \mid f^' (z)\mid ^2 dA(z)$ = $\int_D \mid \sum_1^\infty na_n z^n-1 \mid^2 dA(z)$  **=**  $\sum_1^\infty n\mid a_n \mid^2$. 
Question: Why is the last equality true?

Comment: You want $\|f\|^2=\int_D|f'(z)|^2dA(z)$, not $\|f\|$.  You can enclose exponents in `{` and `}`.  E.g., `$z^n-1$` gives you $z^n-1$, whereas `$z^{n-1}$` gives you $z^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$|f'(z)|^2=f'(z)\overline{f'(z)}=\left(\sum_1^\infty ma_mz^{m-1}\right)\left(\sum_1^\infty n\overline{a_n}\overline{z}^{n-1}\right)
=\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty mna_m\overline{a_n}z^{m-1}\overline{z}^{n-1}.$$

Integration term-by-term is justified by uniform convergence on compact sets, and $\int_D z^{m-1}\overline{z}^{n-1} dA(z)$ is an easy computation using polar coordinates that will give you the desired sum.

Comment: I should have clarified, by the unit disc I meant: the set $\mid z\mid <1$. This is not a compact set, and your uniform convergence argument doesn't hold

Comment: @Rohan: I know what you meant, but I'm glad you're looking for clarification since my answer wasn't clear.  For $r<1$, let $D_r=\{z:|z|\leq r\}$.  Then for each integrable $g:D\to\mathbb{C}$, $\int_D g(z)dA(z)=\lim_{r\to 1}\int_{D_r}g(z)dA(z)$.  The series in question converge uniformly on each $D_r$.

Comment: yes, it makes sense. That's a good way to look at it. Thanks!